# Matrix in assembly mxn dimension

Tags: assembly, x86

I made a code in assembly 8086. I load matrix (array) in memory with dimension 3x3. but this code works just for this dimension of matrix 3x3. Could someone give me an idea how could i make it to work with dimension m x n? the array is loaded in memory and at the end just print the result, another array. thanks

```
; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
matrix db 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ; load matrix in memory

ends

stack segment
dw 128 dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax



mov bx, matrix ; move matrix to offset bx
mov ch, 3
mov cl, 0


COLUMNAHEAD: 

mov dl, [bx] ; get the first element of matrix in dl
add dl, 30h ; add to show number
mov ah, 02h
int 21h ; print first number
inc cl 

cmp cl, ch ; compare if the counter is at the end of column


jge ROWAHEAD ; if greater go to row
add bx, 3 ; if not inc offset for 3 
jmp COLUMNAHEAD





ROWAHEAD:
inc cl ; 1 element of roe
inc bx ; inc offset for one place
mov dl, [bx] ; get the number in dl
add dl, 30h ; convert to number
mov ah, 02h
int 21h ; print the number

cmp cl, 5 
je COLUMNAHEAD
jne ROWAHEAD 


COLUMNBACK:
inc cl 
sub bx, 3
mov dl, [bx]
add dl, 30h
mov ah, 02h
int 21h 
cmp cl, 7
jne COLUMNBACK 
je ROWBACK

ROWBACK:
dec bx 
mov dl, [bx] 
add dl, 30h
mov ah, 02h
int 21h 
JMP MIDDLE


MIDDLE:
add bx, 3
mov dl, [bx] 
add dl, 30h
mov ah, 02h
int 21h 

JMP END

END: 


this is the code i wrote. it works for the matrix 
1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9 and print 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3, 2, 5
```

Matrix given in memory to print the spiral in opposite direction from clockwise (left column down the right lower range, right up column, a series of upper left, etc. until you get to the environment). This works just for dimension 3x3. this should works for mxn dimension. but i don't know how, any suggestion???

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: I know how to solve for matrix 3x3, but I need to write the code which works with matrix m=rows and n=columns.... My code which a write above works only for matrix 3x3..

Comment: Yes, but which part of that is the problem?  It already seems that you've mastered assembly.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know, how to write the algorithm for matrix with N dimension, for example 4x4 , 4x5, 5x4....etc. not only for fixed matrix like my matrix which works 3x3.

Comment: Would you know how to write it if you were working in e.g. C?

Comment: Do you know how to write pseudo code or C++ code for this task with matrix with N dimension, and after that I will try to translate this in assembly.

Comment: Can someone help how to write algorithm for this task....

Answer (score 0):

When having a matrix M(rows) x N(cols), one turn of the desired algorithm prints out perimeter of the matrix. The next turn gets (M-2) x (N-2) matrix (which is stored in memory in a special way). This fact allows an efficient iterative formulation.

Let's make use of your algorithm above. Then the turn looks like:

```
COLUMNAHEAD(M); ROWAHEAD(N-1); COLUMNBACK(M-1); ROWBACK(N-2);
```

Here the number of elements to print is shown in parentheses. The algorithm should be stopped when any of these numbers reaches 0.

So, you need aside of the matrix itself the following variables:

```
- pointer to the current element (your ds:bx)
- values M and N, kept until algorithm stopped
- shift parameter, let be D
```

In more details the sketch of the required algorithm looks like:

```
D := 0
label:
if (M-D==0) stop
COLUMNAHEAD(M-D)
inc D
if (N-D==0) stop
ROWAHEAD(N-D)
if (M-D==0) stop
COLUMNBACK(M-D)
inc D
if (N-D==0) stop
ROWBACK(N-D)
goto label
```

Particular attention should be paid to correct indexation (using M and 1 as displacement values). Simple optimizations like minimizing the instruction number in cycles guided by decrementing variables (DEC/JZ or even LOOP) or better register usage (si instead of bx) are advisable too. Also note that matrices are usually stored in memory by columns (then 1 and N become correct displacements).

Comment: I tried to apply your code in my code, but I don't understand at all. could you try to fix in my code?? Your explanation was good but I don't have to much experience. If you could try to write program according your explanation will be very useful for me. Thanks in advance Olion